# Ralink RT3090 in Ubuntu 14.04 -- Very bad reception + keeps disconnecting

Tags: wireless, 14.04, ralink

I've upgraded from 12.04 (actually Mint 13) to 14.04 (actually Mint 17) (64bit), and my Wifi reception with my Ralink RT3090 is now very bad. I only get good connectivity if I'm in the same room as my wifi router, whereas previously or in Windows 7 I could connect to the router from a significantly larger distance. Also, the nm-applet now shows only 2 networks tops (the strongest ones), whereas previously I'd get a very long list.

Since the wifi still works well in Windows 7, this shouldn't be a hardware issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

1. Open terminal
2. Write if you have leafpad:

   ```
   sudo leafpad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

   if you have gedit:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
3. Add these lines at the end of the file:

   ```
   blacklist rt2800usb
   blacklist rt2x00lib
   blacklist rt2x00pci
   blacklist rt2x00usb
   blacklist rt2800mmio
   blacklist rt2x00m
   ```
4. Save and close the file
5. Reboot.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Ralink drivers don't work well with the newer kernel and are having all kinds of problems. It defaults to the **ra2800** drivers which doesn't seem to want to work well with Wireless N networks.

Check your **dmesg** for `rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout` errors, if you find a whole bunch of them then this is probably what's causing your network issues.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62781

Comment: My wifi's really on `rt2800pci`, though. Ergo, `rt2800usb` shouldn't have anything to do with it. So what do you think I should do? Start a new bug report on that site for the  `rt2800pci` module on `uname -srv`(=Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014) with relevant `dmesg` errors attached and wait till someone fixes it?

Comment: Done that. Hopefully someone fixes it. Thanks for the reply!