# Bad WIFI Connection (Ralink RT3090)

Tags: 14.04, networking, ralink

Linux newbie here.  I've tried looking at other threads, but haven't been able to figure this out.

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32 Bit) on an Asus 1015PEM netbook with a Ralink RT3090 wifi card.  I did a complete install and wiped Windows 7 off the system.

Wifi worked great with 7, I had a 65 Mbps connection.  Now it drops to 6 or 1 Mbps and I cannot connect Wirelessly.

Here is part of what I got with lshw:

*-network
       description: Wireless interface 
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe 
       vendor: Ralink corp. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       logical name: wlan0 
       version: 00 
       serial: 48:5d:60:6a:80:9e 
       width: 32 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.2.0-30-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbff0000-fbffffff

Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink RT3090 in Ubuntu 14.04 -- Very bad reception + keeps disconnecting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/478018/ralink-rt3090-in-ubuntu-14-04-very-bad-reception-keeps-disconnecting)

Comment: Also is your network/router set to Wireless N?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I have also tried b/g/n.

Comment: Do you mean you tried setting your router to only broadcast b only, then g only and then n only? With my laptop I had to disable wireless n either at the router or on the laptop to prevent the issues you're also having. However my card is different, I have the Intel Centrino Wiressless N.

Comment: No.  I used the performance mode n setting only, and then tried the compatibility mode b/g/n.  I really don't want to disable n and slow down my other connections.

Comment: I recommend you try disabling n at the router to see how your WiFi card reacts. If it proves to be stable when n is disabled, then you can enable n and find solutions to disable n on Ubuntu, since the drivers for n compatibility for that card is poor. I have to disable n for my Intel card for the same reason - but to diagnose it is easier to see how the system reacts when n isn't available.

Comment: @RickR , could you override this issue? I have the same problem..

Comment: @efkan  Never solved this issue, even with all upgrades.  I just use my realtek usb adapter.

Answer (score 0):

What is your current kernel?

You can find that thru a uname - r
https://www.kernel.org
Check if your version is the latest if not
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/02/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-3-in-linux.html?m=1

Follow the instructions on the link below and select 32 or 64 according to your distro type.

This happened on a laptop of mine and updating kernel sorted the problem maybe this can fix your problem as well

Comment: I had an older one and updated to 4.4.3.  Still no good.  I have been using a T Link micro usb adapter, which uses a Realtek driver and works fine.  Still, I'd rather have the internal one working.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Eoan 19.10, you have to edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file and to add at the end of this file

```
#blacklist rt2800pci 
blacklist rt2800lib 
blacklist rt2800mmio 
blacklist rt2x00usb 
#blacklist rt2x00pci 
blacklist rt2x00lib 
blacklist rt2x00mmio 
#blacklist rt2860sta
```

Source : [Dsfc](https://www.dsfc.net/logiciel-libre/linux/ubuntu-linux-logiciel-libre/installer-le-driver-de-la-carte-wifi-a-base-de-chipset-ralink-rt3090-sur-kubuntu/)